# Compress a 1GB file into 200_MB?

Tags: compression, archiving

So I just downloaded MySQL for Windows 64bit which **211.9MB** but when I extracted it it is now **1.05GB**. How did they do it? They archive wasn't damaged at all nor corrupted.

Before (Compressed):

[image]

After: (Uncompressed):

[image]

I was just totally amazed, I thought this wasn't possible. Archive info from WinRar:

[image]

Comment: If it was damaged or corrupt it wouldn't have extracted in the first place.

Comment: You've never received an attachment that would uncompress to 128 TB binary zeroes followed by "You've been zipped"?

Comment: noped, I have not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compression ratio used may depend on the files that are being compressed. A text file with one million "ABC" will probably have a very good compression ratio. Additionally, they have probably chosen a good compression algorithm and the highest possible settings.

Comment: Create a 1GB file with all bytes the same and it'll indeed compress fairly spectacularly!

Comment: People used to create "archive bombs" like this. You'd email a tiny zip file to someone, their mail server's AV would extract it, find another archive, extract it, run out of memory, and crash. I've got a 6kb gzip file somewhere that, when fully extracted, is something like 40GB..

Answer (score 4):

[Deflate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE_%28algorithm%29) is one of the most used compression algorithms. It searches for patterns on the data and stores it on a dictionary. The more "repetitive" a file is, the more it can be compressed. A very good explanation of the algorithm can be found [here](http://zlib.net/feldspar.html).

Comment: Once I wrote a script to test 7zip power by compressing a 3gb txt full of 1's. The result was a file of ~60kb

Comment: That's not very good compression for such a file. Did you try to re-compress the compressed file?

Comment: Actually I started sending the file to my friends as a prank

Answer (score 2):

Different files can be compressed to different sizes.
For example, if you compress bitmap or text files, you'll get high results.
It also depends on compressor program and its method of compression (just use [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) instead of [WinRAR](http://rarlab.com/download.htm) and you'll see that it compresses much better).

Recently I've found **KGB Archiver**, which is probably the best high-compression tool  for today.
I couldn't believe that file which size is **~1GB** can be compressed **to some MBs**, but it could do it!!
So 19% compressed archive seems nothing compared to it ;)
It uses **PAQ6** algorithm, thus it needs a lot of CPU and RAM to compress.
Now it's an open-source project and is located in SourceForge. You can download it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kgbarchiver/).

Comment: "KGB Archiver, which is probably the best high-compression tool today" - PAQ6 has many successors now which are much better. Of course, these aren't suitable for general use because the RAM/CPU/time requirements are just too high for both compression and decompression.

Comment: @Karan Can you tell us some of their names??

Comment: @SEARAS: The Wikipedia article on PAQ is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Your question inspired me to do some research and learn a little bit about compression works.

How did they do it? Basically, lots of [epic math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_data_compression#Lossless_compression_techniques), but one basic method is [Huffman Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding)

The file is divided into chunks, those chunks are sorted into a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29), with the most common blocks being given the shortest location names in the tree. The zip is created from a description of the tree followed a list of addresses in the tree required to rebuild the file. Sometimes a pre-computed tree is used this eliminates the need to share the tree. The more repetitious the program, the smaller the tree and better the compression. There is so much more to it then this though, [it's complicated.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZW)