# How would Apache or Compressed HTTP react to a zip bomb?

Tags: security, apache-http-server, compression, zip

inspired by [Compress a 1GB file into 200_MB?](https://superuser.com/questions/554267/compress-a-1gb-file-into-200-mb/554269#554269) and the related comments:

Many webservers today use a zipped HTTP Version (Gzip afaik).

How would Apache or any other server react to a zip bomb? Since the files are compressed, one could just send a prepared file and the target server would extract it to several GB/TB? Or is this in some way prevented? And when, how?

I hope I will not see the Internet crash due to this question ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be absolutely certain that there are people out there who spend a significant amount of time trying to crash Apache web servers externally, just as you can be sure that the [Apache Software Foundation](http://www.apache.org/) spends a significant amount of time testing their software to ensure that this type of attack will not succeed.

To specifically address your question; Apache uses [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) to compress and decompress data sent and received. So, the target here is not Apache but the module used for handling compressed files.

Given that zip bombs are a well known vector of attack, and that it is possible to craft a request containing a maliciously formed zip object, this type of attack would fail.

You can be certain that the day someone finds a way to attack in this manner the problem will be identified and patched in a very short period of time.

Some applications have specific detection routines to detect and handle zip bombs.

Comment: Ok. I have guessed myself, that they have tested it (at least i would be very, very surprised if they missed it). I just don't KNOW what they have tested and what not.

Comment: That is a good question. Many open source projects use formal bug tracking or issue tracking software for this reason. Start here: https://issues.apache.org/  Bugzilla and Jira are common tool for this purpose. Have a search through their history.

Comment: Here is one of them: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50090 Bug 50090 - 'zip' bomb prevention